# Using a rakefile to generate docs from source

Tags: ruby, rake, yard

I downloaded the ruby Twitter gem source code and am trying to generate the documentation using yard, which I installed via `gem install yard`. In the rakefile, I found the following, which I assume is used to generate the docs for the Twitter gem:

```
require 'yard'
YARD::Rake::YardocTask.new
```

I tried to `require yard` in irb and then run `YARD::Rake::YardocTask.new` but nothing happened.

Can you help me get on the right track?

Comment: @AdamEberlin but can you confirm how I'm supposed to do it> Do I go into irb and run that command and it'll generate Twitter api docs?

Comment: Am I the only one who before getting to the post typed "yard rake" into google and was confused by the results?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [the YARD docs](https://github.com/lsegal/yard#usage):

> The second most obvious is to generate docs via a Rake task. You can
>   do this by adding the following to your `Rakefile`:
>
> ```
> YARD::Rake::YardocTask.new do |t|
>   t.files   = ['lib/**/*.rb', OTHER_PATHS]   # optional
>   t.options = ['--any', '--extra', '--opts'] # optional
> end
> ```
>
> both the `files` and `options` settings are optional. `files` will
>   default to `lib/**/*.rb` and `options` will represents any options you
>   might want to add. Again, a full list of options is available by
>   typing `yardoc --help` in a shell. You can also override the options
>   at the Rake command-line with the OPTS environment variable:
>
> ```
> $ rake yard OPTS='--any --extra --opts'
> ```

To summarize: after adding `YARD::Rake::YardocTask.new` to your `Rakefile`, run `rake yard`.

Comment: Note that the block is actually optional. According to [the doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/0.9.5/YARD/Rake/YardocTask#initialize-instance_method), you can change the name of the task if you like.

Comment: But what is really OTHER_PATHS? I'm not able to include any extra files.

Comment: @NathanLilienthal - I can only assume/hope that YARD was named for the sake of this pun. I smell a backronymic apronym...